# ionic ios build wkwebview not start, stuck at splash screen

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

I build app to ios. Apple drop back the relese with UIWebview not supported. I add plugin `Cordova WKWbView Engine` and add this lines to config.xml

```
        <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
        </feature>
        <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

After build, start the app but stuck at splash screen.
No error, and no inspectable device.

Comment: I don't think thats the right package. Please try with this. <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="4.0.0" />

Comment: if i use that plugin validation throw back, UIWebView not supported anymore.

Comment: What version of ionic are you using. We use ionc5 with this plug in and do not have that issue.

Comment: I use that too.

Comment: The final solution was to use capacitor, insteed of cordova.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Any solution found to fix this in cordova. Please help

Comment: @AishApp unfortunately i couldn't solve the problem so i switched to capacitor it works perfectly

Comment: Well I got it resolved by deleting and installing the splash screen plugin again in the cordova platform

Comment: Hi, Have you solved the issue? I'm having same. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: @Kavindhi my solve is change cordova to capacitor, it work fine now.